# Picking a time range between two dates

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a solution where it limits a date range with times. Example I have a dataset with times ranging from `2014-10-25T01:00Z to 2014-10-25T23:00Z`.

Before I go on making a hacky solution myself, I wanted to ask if there's an existing front-end solution where a user can select a time range *within* the above predefined range.

There seem to be various datetime pickers and even datetime-range pickers. But they only have the ability to enable a date range, NOT a datetime range. So In the above example, I'll have to enable 24th and 25th both, and then add a hacky javascript step to validate the user's time selection.

Any nifty solutions? If nothing preexisting, any tips to implement this myself apart from the obvious?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can easily validate if chosen datetime is between two datetimes. If there is a plugin then it should provide events where you can add validation. Choose a plugin first.

Comment: @Tibbers Please review [ask] to see what's not allowed. This question is ***not*** off-topic, and shame on you if you have flagged it as such.